# Nilpotent matrix and relation between its powers and dimension of kernels

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

Given a 4x4 matrix $T$ over $\mathbb{R}$ such that $T^4 = 0 $, $k_i = \textsf{dim} Ker(T^i)$, I need to check which of the following sequences, $$k_1\leq k_2 \leq k_3 \leq k_4,$$ is NOT possible :

$ 1)\; 1\leq 3 \leq 4 \leq 4$

$2) \; 2\leq3\leq4\leq4$

$3) \; 3 \leq 4 \leq 4\leq 4$

$4)\; 2 \leq 4 \leq 4 \leq 4$

The only relevant thing I could recall relating to this is the fact that for nilpotent operators $$ \{0 \} \subset Ker(T) \subset Ker(T^2) \subset \ldots \subset Ker(T^{n-1})$$
But the equality in the choices is putting me off. A hint would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a very basic and easy-to-prove result:

**Lemma:** Let $T$ be an endomorphism on an $n$-dimensional vectorspace. Denote $k_i = \dim \operatorname{Ker} T^i$. Note that $k_0 = 0$, since $T^0$ is defined to be the identity map. The sequence $(k_i)_{i \geq 0}$ is increasing, while the sequence of differences $(k_{i+1}-k_i)_{i \geq 0}$ is decreasing.

(This Lemma immediately rules out your possibility 1)

The first statement is trivial, since we have $\operatorname{Ker} T^i \subset \operatorname{Ker} T^{i+1}$.

Let us prove the second statement:
Denote $b_i = \dim \operatorname{Im} T^i$. Since we have $b_i+k_i = n$ for all $i$, we have $k_{i+1}-k_i = b_i-b_{i+1}$, so it suffices to show, that the latter sequence decreases. For that, just consider the map
$$T:\operatorname{Im} T^i \to V$$
and use dimension formula: The image is $\operatorname{Im} T^{i+1}$ and the kernel is $\operatorname{Im} T^i \cap \operatorname{Ker} T$, so we get
$$b_i = b_{i+1} + \dim \operatorname{Im} T^i \cap \operatorname{Ker} T$$ or
$$b_i-b_{i+1} = \dim \operatorname{Im} T^i \cap \operatorname{Ker} T$$, which is decreasing, since we have $\operatorname{Im} T^i \supset \operatorname{Im} T^{i+1}$ for all  $i$.

---

As stated, this rules out something like $0 \leq 1 \leq 3 \leq 4$.

A **corollary** is the following famous result: Once we have $\dim \operatorname{Ker} T^i = \dim \operatorname{Ker} T^{i+1}$, we have $\dim \operatorname{Ker} T^j = \dim \operatorname{Ker} T^i$ for all $j \geq i$.

We also get the following **corollary**: Let $T$ be nilpotent with one-dimensional kernel. Then the kernel of $T^j$ is $j$-dimensional for any $j \leq n$.

---

As a constructive result, let us note that the lemma above is the only restriction for the sequence $(k_i)_{i \geq 0}$:

Let $(k_i)_{i \geq 0}, k_0=0$ be an increasing sequence, such that $(k_{i+1}-k_i)$ is decreasing and eventually stabilizes at zero. Then there exists an $n > 0$ and an endomorphism $T$ on an $n$-dimensional vector space, such that $k_i = \dim \operatorname{Ker} T^i$.

The proof is simply the Jordan form.

In particular your possibilites 2)-4) are all possible.

Comment: You have my gratitude. This was what I was looking for. Is there any book that has results like these which could come in handy while solving problems in Linear Algebra??

Comment: To be honest, I cannot remember to have seen that result in a text book. It is just something, that comes into your mind, if you understand the mechanism behind the Jordan form: Take a Jordan form matrix and consider its powers. Anytime you increase the power, each block with at least one $1$ remaining, contributes to the increase of dimension of the kernel by exactly one. A block of starting size $m$ will be eventually vanishing at the $m$-th power. So the amount of "blocks alive", which contribute the dimensional increase of the kernel, only gets lower and lower...

Comment: That was very neatly put. I guess I have to rely on my understanding rather than reach for a book for any and every result.

Comment: By the way: It might be worth while coming up with a rigorous proof of the constructive result, which is of course a little bit technical. You should make sure to point out, where we really need the difference sequence to be decreasing in order to make the proof work.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the possible lists [invariant factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_factor)
of $T$.  Since $T$ is $4 \times 4$, then its characteristic polynomial is $T^4$.  The invariant factors must divide the characteristic polynomial, hence are all of the form $T^i$.  The characteristic polynomial is the product of all invariant factors, so the list of invariant factors must be $T^{i_1}, T^{i_2}, \ldots, T^{i_t}$, where $i_1, \ldots, i_t$ are positive integers, and $i_1 + \cdots + i_t = 4$.  Moreover, each invariant factor divides the following invariant factor, so we have $i_1 \leq \cdots \leq i_t$.  The possible partitions of $4$ are:
\begin{align*}
4 &= 4\\
4 &= 3+1\\
4 &= 2 + 2\\
4 &= 2 + 1 + 1\\
4 &= 1 + 1 + 1+ 1
\end{align*}
Let $k$ be our base field.  We consider $k^4$ as a $k[x]$-module where $x$ acts as $T$.  By the [structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain)
, then $k^4$ is isomorphic to one of the following $k[x]$-modules. 
\begin{align*}
\frac{k[x]}{(x^4)} &\longleftrightarrow 1, 2, 3, 4\\
\frac{k[x]}{(x^3)} \oplus \frac{k[x]}{(x)} &\longleftrightarrow 2, 3, 4, 4\\
\frac{k[x]}{(x^2)} \oplus \frac{k[x]}{(x^2)} &\longleftrightarrow 2, 4, 4, 4\\
\frac{k[x]}{(x^2)} \oplus \frac{k[x]}{(x)} \oplus \frac{k[x]}{(x)} &\longleftrightarrow 3, 4, 4, 4\\
\frac{k[x]}{(x)} \oplus \frac{k[x]}{(x)} \oplus \frac{k[x]}{(x)} \oplus \frac{k[x]}{(x)} &\longleftrightarrow 4, 4, 4, 4
\end{align*}
The numbers on the right are the corresponding dimensions $\dim(\ker(T^j))$ for $j = 1, \ldots, 4$.  These numbers were obtained by considering the action of $x$ on the standard basis.  For instance, $\frac{k[x]}{(x^3)} \cong k \oplus kx \oplus kx^2$ is a $k$-vector space with basis $1,x,x^2$.  Multiplying by $x$ annihilates $x^2$, but not $1$ or $x$ (because we are modding out by $x^3$).  Similarly, multiplying by $x^2$ annihilates $x$ and $x^2$ but not $1$.

**EDIT:** Alternatively, consider the possible Jordan canonical forms for $T$.  Since $T$ is nilpotent, then its only eigenvalue is $0$, so its Jordan canonical form is
$$
J =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & * & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & * & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & *\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where the $*$ are either $0$ or $1$.  This yields $8$ possibilities for $J$ and with a bit of calculation, one can compute the dimensions of the kernels of $J, J^2, J^3, J^4$ for each $J$.  Actually, it's not so hard to find which list is impossible.  If $\dim(\ker(T)) = 1$, then $T$ has rank $3$, so we must have that its Jordan canonical form is
$$
J =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \, .
$$
As you noted in the comments,
$$
J^2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \, .
$$
and which has a $2$-dimensional kernel.  This rules out the first choice.

Comment: Thanks for your trouble. But I have almost no knowledge of modules as such. Could you explain using a vector space over the reals approach??I guess that would follow as a special case of  what you said. But it would still be very helpful. Thanks again

Comment: Hm, okay.  I imagine that my argument can be rephrased in terms of [generalized eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector).  Have you dealt with these before?  If so, I'll think about it some more tomorrow.

Comment: Another more basic approach would be to write down all the possible Jordan canonical forms $J$ for $T$ and then compute the kernel of $J, J^2, \ldots$ for each one.  It will require a bit more computation, but there aren't that many possibilities for $J$.

Comment: Yes I do know about generalised eigenvectors. Will give it a go myself again before you post your answer.  I was looking for some method that doesnt involve too much computation as this question propped up in a timed exam. But anything helps. Thank you.

Comment: I apologise for not seeing your edit at all. I dont why only your comments were visible. The nullity would be 2 and that would give me my answer.