# For a nilpotent operator $T^{n-1}=0 \iff dim(ker(T))\ge2$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, nilpotence

Since the kernel must grow with each power for a nilpotent operator the the $\Leftarrow$ direction is easy. Why is the other direction true?

Comment: Think about the Jordan normal form.

Comment: \iff gives $\iff$

Comment: Is $n$ the dimension of the space?

Comment: See the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447591/nilpotent-matrix-and-relation-between-its-powers-and-dimension-of-kernels).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove the "$\Rightarrow$" direction use contraposition: assume $\dim(\ker(T))<2$ and show that $T^{n-1}\neq 0$.

If $\dim(\ker(T))=0$ then we are trivially done.

Assume $\dim(\ker(T))=1$, then $T$ has a one dimensional eigenspace associated with the zero eigenvalue and eigen vector $p_0$. Let $P$ be the matrix formed by the generalized eigenvectors of $T$ with $p_0$ as its first column. We then have $$T = PJP^{-1}$$ where $J$ is of the form 
$$J = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0   & \dots & 0 \\
0  & J_1 & \;& \; \\ 
\vdots  & \; & \ddots& \; \\ 
0  & \; & \; & J_p\end{bmatrix},$$
and each $J_l$ is a Jordan block.

We then have $$T^{n-1}=PJ^{n-1}P^{-1}$$ where 
$$J^{n-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0   & \dots & 0 \\
0  & J_1^{n-1} & \;& \; \\ 
\vdots  & \; & \ddots& \; \\ 
0  & \; & \; & J_p^{n-1}\end{bmatrix}.$$
$J^{n-1}$, and therefore $T^{n-1}$, clearly has a one dimensional kernel. We conclude by contraposition that $T^{n-1}=0$ implies $\dim(\ker(T))\geq 2$.